# Empty Flot Charts?

Tags: jquery, flot, bar-chart

I'm running the code below and getting an empty chart using Flot/jQuery.  Ideally what I am after is a bar chart of the data.  I'm looked and looked at this with no joy - does anyone have any ideas?

```
<div id="user_breakdown_placeholder" style="width:300px;height:300px"></div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        var d = [["Unassigned", 310],["Maynard Schumm", 274]];
            var options = {};
        $.plot($("#user_breakdown_placeholder"), d, options);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Flot does not appear to support these type of charts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of flot (v. 0.6) supports bar charts.  Here is an [example](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/graph-types.html).  In your plot() function, you just have to put:

```
bars: { show: true}
```

Answer (score 2):

An old question but I don't think it was answered.  According to the Flot API documentation:

> Note that to simplify the internal logic in Flot both the x and y
>   values must be numbers ... If you're getting mysterious errors, double
>   check that you're inputting numbers and not strings.

If the above case you are using strings in your data (e.g. ["Unassigned", 310]) which isn't going to work according to the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this but you just need to fake up your data a little bit.

```
$(function () {
    var data = [[0, 310],[1,274]];
    var datasets = [ {
                 "data": data
                     }, 
                   ];
    var options = {
                   bars: {show: true},
                   yaxis: { min: 0 },
                   xaxis: { ticks:  [
                                     [0.5, "Unassigned"],
                                     [1.5, "Maynard Schumm"]
                                    ],
                          },
                  };
   $.plot($("#user_breakdown_placeholder"), datasets, options);
});
```

------>

[image]

Presumably you can modify your data appropriately before passing it to Flot.

There are lots of great examples of real uses at [FlotUsage](http://code.google.com/p/flot/wiki/FlotUsage). e.g. [Fedora](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/updates/metrics/) have some nice bar charts. The great thing is because it's JavaScript you can view source and crib ideas from anyone :)

Answer (score 0):

As Neil Middleton says in his comment, Flot does not support Bar Charts.

Perhaps [this](http://www.maxb.net/scripts/jgcharts/include/demo/) or [this](http://www.dumpsterdoggy.com/articles/?jquery-horizontal-bar-graph) plugin can help you?

Comment: I'll give a +++ to the jqcharts plugin cited by Natrium there.  The Google Charts API is very nice, giving you great flexibility.  See the basic API information at: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/