# All,Flot co-ordinates

Tags: asp.net, jquery, flot

I am new to Flot.
I want to show weekly visitors statistics in my projects.
I have to sho the visitors of the month but weekly on Flot.
e.g.
1st week 1-5 there are 500 visitors.
 6-12 there are 900 visitors.
and so on.
And I want to show X coordinates as 1-5,6-12,13-19,....
Can anyone suggest what to do.
Strictly use Flot.

Comment: How far have you got, and what specifically do you need help with? What form do you have the visitor data in - aggregated by day, hour, raw hit times for each visit, etc.?

Comment: Actually ,whatever range i am taking will be fetched from datatbase. in database i am taking sartDate and EndDate , and visitorCount field.
if start date is 1-6-10 and endDate is 5-6-10 the count will be taken.Ihave to simply fetch startDate ,endDate,and visitrCount.and show it on graph,but as 1-5 500 
6-12 700 etc.
that is from 1-6-10 to 5-6-10 there 500 visitors and so on.
I am trying to show x co-ordinates as 1-5,6-12,13-19....
I have included jquery.js file and jquery.flot.js file.
Hope u understood wht i mean to say.
 
Thanks

Comment: I could draw graph using x axis coordiantes as 0,5,10,15,20 ...but i want this as 1-5,6-12,13-19....

Answer (score 0):

Check out the tickFormatter:

> Alternatively, for ultimate control over how ticks look like you can
>   provide a function to "tickFormatter". The function is passed two
>   parameters, the tick value and an "axis" object with information, and
>   should return a string.

So what you're looking for is something like this:

```
$.plot(placeholder, data, {
  //your options here
  xaxis: {
    tickFormatter: function(val,axis){
      return (val+1).toString()+'-'+(val+5).toString();
    }

  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want a plain old bar graph but are getting misled by the fact that you have some date-related data.

In the data you give Flot to graph, use fake numbers as x values that are just increasing integers. So for 1-5 put 0, for 6-12 put 1, and so on.

Then as Ryley says, use the tick formatter to put the labels on the x axis that you want.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943855/empty-flot-charts/3562363#3562363) as an example.